# The definition of a (pseudo-)Dwyer map

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I've looked up the definition in Raptis *Homotopy Theory of Posets*, on the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dwyer+map) and even Cinskies *a classe des morphismes de Dwyer n'est pas stable par rétractes*, but none of these make sense to me. E.g. citing from the nlab:

> A functor of small categories $i \colon C \to D$ is a **Dwyer map** if it is a sieve and factors as a composite of $f \colon C \to C'$ and $j \colon C' \to D$ such that
>
> - $f$ admits a deformation retraction, i.e. a functor $r \colon C' \to C$ such that $r i = \operatorname{id}_C$ toghether with a natural transformation $h \colon i r \to \operatorname{id}_{C'}$ such that $h i = \operatorname{id}_i$,
> - $j$ is a cosieve.

But the composition $ri$ isn't even defined... so I assume it's supposed to be: $rf=\operatorname{id}_C$ and $h\colon fr\to \operatorname{id}_{C'}$. But then, what is $hf=\operatorname{id}_f$ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a natural transformation of functors $\mathcal{C}' \to \mathcal{C}'$, say $h : f r \Rightarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}'}$ and a functor $f : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}'$, we can form a natural transformation $h f : f r f \Rightarrow f$ by taking the components of $h f$ at an object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to be the component $h_{f c}$. You can view all of this homotopy-theoretically and see that the quoted definition really is just a deformation retraction of $f : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}'$.